# Inverting a function

Tags: algorithms, cryptography, one-way-functions

I posted this question [on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242737/inverting-a-function) two years ago but got no answer:

Let $w = a_0 \cdot a_1 \cdots a_{n-1} $ be a word from $ \{0,1\}^n $, $|w| = n$

Let $m = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{ a_i \cdot 2 ^ {n-1-i} } $ be the corresponding binary number constructed
from the word. 
Let $k=  \left \lfloor \frac{n!}{2^n} \right \rfloor \cdot (m+1)$ , then $ 1 \le k \le n! $.

Compute the Lehmer-Permutation $\pi_k$ from $k$ on $n$ numbers.
(
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code
)

Set $ x := \pi_k \cdot w = a_{\pi_k(0)} \cdot a_{\pi_k(1)} \cdots a_{\pi_k(n-1)} $

Then $f(w) := x$.

So the function permutes the digits in the word $w$ and the permutation is determined by $w$.

Suppose you randomly choose uniformly a word from $\{0,1\}^{1000}$ and then you apply the function. Is it practically possible to invert the constructed word?
That is, does somebody have an idea on how to invert the word?

More details may be found on:

http://orgesleka.blogspot.de/2015/09/candidate-one-way-function.html

This picture shows all words of length 7 when f is applied on those words:
[image: graph-7]

Comment: If I understand correctly, given a binary string `w`, compute:
1. `k` as shown above
2.  The factoradic representation of `k` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Definition)
3. Apply this factoradic to `w`

Comment: @KhanPower: Yes this is the definition of the function.

Comment: this question has an answer at mathoverflow

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on Math Overflow.